# Как в GridView при длинном тапе на элементе - плавно изменить размеры всех дочерних элементов

Tags: android, анимация, gridview, android-on-click

Есть `GridView`. Хочу сделать так, чтобы при длинном клике, элементы уменьшались в размере все одновременно, по-типу анимации.

Например, как в галерее фотографий. Когда при длинном клике происходит переход в режим мультивыбора.

Вот пример чего хочу добиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал делать анимацию на элемент - но срабатывает только на первом элементе, несмотря на то, на какой элемент нажимаю.

Сам `GridView` через Adapter и Holder наполняется элементами:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/ticket_image_new"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/grid_ticket_item_layout">

    <TextView
        style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/fbutton_color_clouds"
        android:id="@+id/ticketNumber"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

На элементах прикручены слушатели:

```
ticketsGrid.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parentLong, 
                                       View viewLong, 
                                       int positionLong, 
                                       long idLong) {
            return true;
        }
});
```

и:

```
ticketsGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentShort, 
                                View viewShort, 
                                final int positionShort, 
                                long idShort) {

            return true;
        }
});
```

Может есть готовые библиотеки или кто-то уже делал такое?

Comment: делал примерно такое для `GridLayout` с анимацией веса всех элементов (учитывая, что все они на экране и не скроллятся). На некоторых устройствах может подлагивать, но в целом норм. Если интересен такой вариант, могу поделиться. Правда неуверен, что со скроллом будет работать как надо.

Comment: @Jarvis_J Конечно интересно - это лучше чем ничего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делал для `GridLayout` через анимацию веса и такой класс:

```
public class WeightAnimation implements Animator.AnimatorListener {
    public static final int DURATION = 500;
    private ValueAnimator va;

    WeightAnimation(float from, float to, final View view) {
        va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(from, to); //fromWeight, toWeight
        va.setDuration(DURATION);
        va.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).weight = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                view.requestLayout();
            }
        });
        va.addListener(this);
    }

    public void startAnimation() {
        va.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
       //код по окончанию анимации
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

    }
}
```

Использование, где нужно:

```
 void collapseAnimation(final View view, final boolean isCollapsing) {
        WeightAnimation wa = new WeightAnimation(isCollapsing ? 1f : 0f, isCollapsing ? 0f : 1f, view);
        wa.startAnimation();
 }
```

Передаете все ваши `View`, для нужного `isCollapsing=false`, для остальных `= true`.

По прежнему остается вопрос быстродействия, особенно, если у вас много `View`. Но на небольшое их количество работает стабильно.

Если отслеживать анимацию не нужно - `implements` и `animationListener`'ы можно удалить.

Comment: Попробую переделать, точнее адаптировать под свои нужды.

Comment: Хотя сам пример анимации которым Вы поделились - довольно хорош, но все же он не подошел мне для этого случая. Прикрутил, и вместо `weight` установил `height` и `width`. Итог - иконки скалируются - но иконки все дружно подтягиваются кверху заполняя свободное пространство. Но хуже всего то что при скроле, заметно как на новопоявившихся иконках срабатывает анимация.

Comment: @Jarvis_JБлагодарю за пример- подтолкунули в нужную сторону. Прикрутил `ValueAnimator`. Анимацию запускал непосредственно в адаптере, при заливке `ViewHolder`-ом элементов в `Grid`. Анимировал  ширину и высоту елемента.

Comment: Рад, что мой пример вам помог :)